# Returning the result of a Future in a synchronous call

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

I'm using the signature pad in the FlutterFormBuilder package to capture a signature (FlutterFormBuilderSignaturePad), upload it to firebase storage and then return the download url to the application for storage in a document in firestore.

The problem im facing is that the upload takes a couple of seconds to complete (possibly longer on poor connection). I'm trying to await the call so i can pass the download url to the database however its ignoring my attempts.

Ive tried :

- Chaining my calls using the `.then()` and `.whenComplete()` but valueTransformer still returns a blank string.
- added async to the "valueTransformer", "onSaved" and "onChange" methods and awaited the calls
- moved the logic to save the signature between the three methods above in order to give the uimage time to upload
- onChanges fires a lot so i introduced a _processing flag so it didnt save the image multiple times and cause database timeouts. onChange was returning a url given a few seconds however i couldn't guarantee   the signature was complete.

So my widget looking like this:

```
  final SignatureController _controller = SignatureController(
    penStrokeWidth: 5,
    penColor: Colors.red,
    exportBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  );
  String _signature;
  File _signatureFile;
  bool _processing;

return FormBuilderSignaturePad(
          name: 'signature',
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "signature"),
          initialValue: _signatureFile?.readAsBytesSync(),
          onSaved: (newValue) async {
            //called on save just before valueTransformer
            await processSignature(newValue, context);
          },
          valueTransformer: (value) {
            //called when the form is saved
            return _signature;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            //called frequently as the signature changes
            if (_controller.isNotEmpty) {
              if (_controller.value.length > 19) {
                if (!_processing) {
                  processSignature(value, context).then((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _processing = false;
                    });
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          },
        )
```

My future for processing the upload and setting the state

```
Future<void> processSignature(dynamic signature, BuildContext context) async {
    setState(() {
      _processing = true;
    });
    var bytes = await _controller.toPngBytes();

    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file =
        File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'signature${database.uid}.png'));

    file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);

    var url = await storage.uploadImage(
        context: context,
        imageToUpload: file,
        title: "signature${database.uid}.png",
        requestId: database.currentRequest.id);

    setState(() {
      _signature = url.imageUrl;
      _signatureFile = file;
    });
  }
```

UPDATES AFTER CHANGES BELOW

Process Signature:

```
 Future<String> processSignature(
      dynamic signature, BuildContext context) async {
    var bytes = await _controller.toPngBytes();

    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file =
        File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'signature${database.uid}.png'));

    file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);

    var url = await storage.uploadImage(
        context: context,
        imageToUpload: file,
        title: "signature${database.uid}.png",
        requestId: database.currentRequest.id);

    return url.imageUrl;
  }
```

Signature Pad Widget:

```
return FormBuilderSignaturePad(
          name: 'signature',
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "signature"),
          initialValue: _signatureFile?.readAsBytesSync(),
          onSaved: (newValue) async {},
          valueTransformer: (value) async {
            final savedUrl = await processSignature(value, context);
            return savedUrl;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {},
        );
```

Method where im seeing the "Future"

```
_formKey[_currentStep].currentState.save();
if (_formKey[_currentStep].currentState.validate()) {
                      //request from the database
                      var request = firestoreDatabase.currentRequest;

                      //this should be the url however its returning as 
                      //"Future<String>"
                      var value = _formKey[_currentStep].currentState.value;


                      request.questions[_currentStep].result =
                          jsonEncode(_formKey[_currentStep].currentState.value);

                      request.questions[_currentStep].completedOn =
                          Timestamp.fromDate(new DateTime.now());

                      firestoreDatabase.updateRequest(request).then((value) {
                        if (_currentStep == _totalSteps - 1) {
                          //pop the screen
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            _currentStep++;
                          });
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It impossible to return async result in sync call. `Future` means it completes *somewhere in future*.

Remove `processSignature` from `onChanged` (why send signature each time it modified?) and process it in `onSaved`. Then you can use async/await to send signature to server and wait for result url.

```dart
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  /// Form key
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  /// Contains signature binary daya
  Uint8List signatureValue;

  @override
  void build(...) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        FormBuilderSignaturePad(
          ...
          onSaved(Uint8List value) async {
            signatureValue = value;
          },
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Submit'),
          onPressed: () {
            _submit();
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }  

  /// Submits form
  Future< void> _submit() async {
    if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      formKey.currentState.save(); // calls all `onSaved` for each form widgets
      // So at this point you have initialized `signatureValue`
      try {
        final signatureUrl = await processSignature(signatureValue, context); // save into database
        await doSomethingWithUrl(signatureUrl); // insert into document
      } on SomeExceptionIfRequired catch (e) {
        // Show error if occurred
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackbar(...);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the async tag to onsaved and included the await but it runs valuetransfor before it finishes

Comment: You should place the code of `processSignature` in a callback which is `final` in sequence of calls.

Comment: I have moved processsignature to valuetransformer and it's now returning a string "Future<string>" and not the value . All calls are awaited

Comment: Put your midified code here or somewhere.

Comment: Refactor your `processSignature` so it returns `Future<String>`, then call it in `valueTransformer` callback. See snippet in my answer.

Comment: Ive updated my question above with some more information. Thanks again really appreciate the help

Comment: I've updated the answer. I've create a simplified code sample which you may adapt for your needs.